# tomcat java php

Tags: java, php, tomcat

I want to use tomcat tomcat, java & php altogether.  my java program creates a text file and write something on the file, when I run that not file is getting created. java program is running through command line. I am keeping all files in /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/testjava. 
Content of Java File:

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
    try{
           Writer fos = null;
                   File outputFile = new File("outList.txt");            
                   fos = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));
                   fos.write("hi");
                   fos.write("\n");
                   fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Content of PHP file:

```
<?php
    $output = exec("java test", $ret);
echo $ret;
    echo file_get_contents("outList.txt");
    echo "HI";
?>
```

$ret given output as Array. HI is getting displayed.

One More Thing when I do php index.php on command line it is working, mean outList.txt is getting created.

var_dump($ret) is giving :

```
HTTP Status 500 -
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.RuntimeException: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/testjava/index.php on line 7

    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.handle(FastCGIServlet.java:499)
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.doGet(FastCGIServlet.java:521)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

java.lang.RuntimeException: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/testjava/index.php on line 7

    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.parseBody(FastCGIServlet.java:409)
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.execute(FastCGIServlet.java:433)
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.handle(FastCGIServlet.java:481)
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.doGet(FastCGIServlet.java:521)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.12 logs.
```

Comment: In order to see the contents of `$ret`, use `var_dump($ret)`. That should give you more information.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for starters your filenames are different between the Java and PHP code (`outList.txt` vs `out.txt`).  Is this an error when posting the question or a real error in code?

Otherwise, I'd encourage you to have a look at the return value and error output (if any) of the PHP `exec` call - it's likely that the Java invocation is failing to run correctly and inspecting these will tell you why.  There could be many reasons - `java` not found on the path for the user running the PHP preprocessor, the `test.class` file not found in whatever the classpath is set up as, etc.  Being able to run the Java command interactively, and having it run by the webserver, are very different things as this is highly environment-dependent.

Comment: In both it was outList.txt only. When I put Like $output = exec("java test", $ret); echo $ret; It is giving Array. How to check other thing u have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

does your php works?

try running:   echo "xxx";

in some php file

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is on line 7 of `index.php`, but that's where the problem seems to be. It's probably the line where you `exec` your java file. Most likely reason I can think of is that the server does not have permission to execute the java test app, or the app does not have proper permissions to create the text file.

The reason it does work when you run the php script from the command prompt is that you're probably the owner of the files and folders and when you run the php script it executes the java app with your userid and permissions. When you call the script via your browser it gets executed with the tomcat userid and permissions, which probably do not allow creating new files.

As a quick test you could make the folder in which the file should be created world writable by setting the permissions to 777. If it then works, you may want to look into a safer setting.

Comment: I have given the whole directory permission like chmod -R 777 dirName .... No use